# Moving My Ubuntu from a USB to My main SSD

Tags: usb, ssd

I Have recently moved to Ubuntu from Windows. I tried it by installing it on a USB instead of my main drive. But now i would like to move it to mt main drive. But i do not want to start from scratch. I would like to have any data on my USB to moved to a partition on my ssd. Is there  any way for me to achieve it. Thanks.

Comment: Others may differ, but I suggest just doing a full install to main drive. If USB is a full install, you can just copy /home over to new install and all your settings will be the same. And you can export a list of installed apps to make it easy to reinstall. I find a new install to SSD is 10 Min. & copy data, install apps & some system configs take an hours total. Trying to copy, reinstall boot loader, edit UUIDs as duplicates not allowed and understanding how to do all that will take a lot longer.

Comment: Above @oldfred is dead on. When you do the fresh install make sure you use the same username and host name.  That will simplify things.

Comment: If it is a Full install to USB you can clone it to HDD using dd.  `sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sda` where sdb is the USB and sda is a blank SSD. This will overwrite everything on the SDD. After clone the partitions on the SDD can be enlarged using GParted. If there are other OS on the SSD please explain. Windows bootloader does not work with Linux. If SSD already has a Linux install, the USB / partition can be cloned using GParted copy/paste. A grub.cfg edit. will add it to the boot menu.

Comment: If SSD already has a Windows install you can do a fresh install and use GParted copy/paste to overwrite the Ubuntu / (and /home if it exists), partitions then edit grub.cfg, (and /etc/fstab), to adjust the UUID's.